# Indicating success with an Ajax script from a form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, image-processing

I have a form that manipulates the size of an image that is posted via this ajax script.  The script and my controller work fine.  My question is, how do I append a success message to this jquery script?  If I used the regular $.ajax() script it would be easy.

I obtained this script through using form torch for codeigniter and would like to learn how to indicate success with it. The "function(data)" appears to me to be there to indicate failure although I dont understand how that is triggered. It doesnt work anyways if the form is submitted empty.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#form").submit(function() {
    var image = $("#image").val(); 
    $.post("/post/process", { image:image },
    function(data){
        $("#image_error").html(data.image);
    },'json');
});
});//this comes from form torch
```

The controller is the standard stuff for image manipulation
The form

```
<?=form_open("/post/process", 'onsubmit="return false;" id="form"')?>
<p>
<label for="image">Image</label>
<span id="image_error" class="error"></span>
<input type="text" name="image" id="image" />
```

I would like to add something like this at the bottom of the form

```
 <div id="success"></div>
```

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I prefer to you the `$.ajax` function because it gives you just one function you can use for all AJAX calls.  In addition, it allows you to provide two functions: one to be executed if the request succeeds and the other to be executed if the request fails.

According to the documentation (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), the `$.post` method only calls the function you specify if the operation succeeds.

Also, if you need to make the script wait for an indication of success or failure before the user does anything else, consider using the `$.ajax` method with the `async:false` parameter.

There are several ways to accomplish what you described:  one way would be to write something like this for the function you pass to `$.post`:

```
function(data)
{
    $(document).append('<div id="succeed"></div>');
}
```

Comment: In other words, if I can show success, I am only showing the .post success not the image processing success if I use the script the way I have it?

Comment: I am going to revert this jquery to the normal .ajax as advised. And throw in the jquery validation plugin for good measure Thanks to both of you for your answers

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not mistaken, you can do something similar to this:

```
response = $.post(...);
```

And response can hold success and error messages.
Than, u can check it using if-condition and write to your div:

```
$("#success").html('your html')
```

Comment: That makes sense. I will try that with this script.

Comment: For some reason the response = .post didnt work, probably because I did it werong.  I tried it then used if(response) etc but once I added the response = .post it would no longer post  Thanks for your thoughts Dmitriy

Comment: U're welcome. In my opinion, it's better to use $.ajax with POST type. It has two great function, what to do if success and what to if error. So, i were you, i world use $.ajax